# Getting the "context" text of a matched group

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the Matcher class of Java to get some strings, now when I get my matches, I also find their begin index and end index. Now what I want to do is get the **x** preceding and proceeding characters.

So what I did was just call the substring method on  the string with `{begin index minus`**x**`}` to `{end index plus`**x**`}`, but it seems to be a little heavy, for every match, I'll have to loop the string for it's context.

I wanted to know whether there's a better way to do that.

Here is what I've done so far:
The part that bothers me is the `text.substring`, how expensive is it

```
    String text = "Some 22 text with 44 characters";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}").matcher(text);
    int x = 5;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group();
        int start = matcher.start();
        int end = matcher.end();
        String pretext = text.substring(start - x, start);
        String postext = text.substring(end, end + x);
        System.out.println(pretext + " - " + match + " - " + postext);
    }
```

Suggested answer of using grouping to solve this:
using the `regex (.{5})(\d{2}(.{5})`.
First of all, this wouldn't be able to captures ones without at least 5 characters before it. So the solution to that is `(.{0,5})(\d{2})(.{0.5})`, very nice for that simple regex `(\d{2})`but for one like "`c?at`" and the given text "cat" this would match the groups

1. c
2. at
3. 

Comment: Show some code. It's difficult to answer questions without seeing what you have actually tried..

Comment: is your `x` fixed or variable?

Comment: I've added what I've done, and yes x is a fixed variable

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = "Some 22 text with 44 characters";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.{5})(\\d{2})(.{5})").matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " - " + matcher.group(2) + " - " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

output :

```
Some  - 22 -  text
with  - 44 -  char
```

Comment: That's fine for a simple regular expression, but one which involves optional characters wouldn't work right with this. I'll give an example in the post itself

Comment: "First of all, this wouldn't be able to captures ones without at least 5 characters before".But you said that 5 is a fixed .{0,5} means 0,1,2,3,4,5 characters will be matched

Comment: Also i didn't understand this sentence : " very nice for that simple regex (\d{2}) but for one like "c?at" and the given text "cat" this would match the groups
c
at
 3."

Comment: The center group of the regex wouldn't match what I want it to